# MongoDB: Try to get explanation on aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I try to get information on an aggregate I do on MongoDB 3.2.5 using `{explain:true}` in order to see if my indices are used :

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
  "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [2.48043, 49.14128]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "maxDistance": 500
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "date": {
      $gt: new ISODate("2016-01-01T01:01:01Z")
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "score": -1,
    "distance": 1
  }
}], {
  explain: true
});
```

As a result I only got the stages aggregate :

```
{
  "waitedMS": NumberLong(0),
  "stages": [{
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.48043,
          49.14128
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "distance",
      "limit": NumberLong(100),
      "maxDistance": 500,
      "query": {

      },
      "spherical": true,
      "distanceMultiplier": 1
    }
  }, {
    "$match": {
      "date": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2016-01-01T01:01:01Z")
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$sort": {
      "sortKey": {
        "score": -1,
        "distance": 1
      }
    }
  }],
  "ok": 1
}
```

I don't have any information about doc scanned, index used, etc...

Can someone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

as per manual

> The operation returns a cursor with the document that contains
>   detailed information regarding the processing of the aggregation
>   pipeline. For example, the document may show, among other details,
>   ***which index, if any, the operation used.***

So there is a kind of ambiguity, but probably if you swap `$geoNear` with `$match` - explain should show something more.

Comment: If i follow the manual, $geoNear must be the first stage in a aggregate pipeline... no ?

Comment: ok @CedricLecocq that could be a case why indexes aren't included in explain entry (and event they could not be used)

Comment: I tried to swap $geoNear and $match but i got an error as i expected...
If i remove the $geoNear stage, i got a $cursor stage on the explanation with the kind of information i'm searching for...